# Directly passing a List to a method fails but wrapping it into a variable works

Tags: dart

Some magic is going on which is shaking my basics:

```
void main() {
  method(['1', '2']); // fails

  final list = ['1', '2'];
  method(list); // works
}

void method(List<Object> objects) {
  List<String> strings = objects;
}
```

Can anyone explain the reason behind this magic?

Comment: Seems like something you should try report to the Dart project: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues

Comment: I notice if you cast it as a List<String> (linter complains about unnecessary cast), or define the method() parameters as List<String> it works fine. Appears Dart cannot correctly infer the type when you use method(['1', '2'])

Comment: Using `method(<String>['1', '2'])` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart type inference infers missing types for an expression based on the expectations of the surrounding context and on the types of the sub-expressions.
It gives more weight to the "context type".

In the first case `method(['1', '2']);`, the context type of the list literal is `List<Object>`. That's the parameter type of `method`. Since the only type missing from the list literal is the list element type itself, and `List<Object>` is what is being asked for, the compiler infers `method(<Object>['1', '2']);`.
That creates a `List<Object>`, passes it to `method`, which then tries to down-cast that to `List<String>`. That fails because a `List<Object>` is not a `List<String>`, not even if all its members are (currently) strings.

In the second case, `final list = ['1', '2'];` there is no context type. So, lacking that, the element type is inferred from the actual elements. Since they are all strings, the compiler infers `final list = <String>['1', '2'];`.
That `List<String>` is then passed to `method` as a `List<Object>` (that's fine because a `List<String>` is a `List<Object>`), and it's then down-cast back to `List<String>`, which works because it is one.

So, the difference is in the context type of the list literal.

Comment: Please open your SO more frequently than Github. We need you here more than on anywhere else :)